# boost::filesystem::path accepts wstring on linux machine

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

As per the boost [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html) char is used on unix systems for `boost::filesystem::path` internal value type. But on linux the following code compiles and also works properly.

```
const std::wstring &m_blobStore;
boost::filesystem::path dir(m_sharePath.begin(), m_sharePath.end());
cout<<dir.string(); // prints the value stored as wstring.
```

Expectation is that if the `m_blobStore`  has been `string` instead of `wstring` only then it should work on linux machines. Can this behaviour be relied on.

Answer (score 1):

Under the `path` constructor section in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-constructors) you find:

```
template <class InputIterator>   path(InputIterator begin,
InputIterator end, const codecvt_type& cvt=codecvt());
```

> Effects: Stores the contents [begin,end) or source in pathname. If the contents are in the generic format and the generic format is
>   unacceptable to the operating system's API, they are converted to the
>   native format. [Note: For ISO/IEC 9945 and Windows implementations,
>   the generic format is already acceptable as a native format, so no
>   generic to native conversion is performed. --end note]
>
> Remarks: If the value type of  [begin,end) or source is not value_type, conversion is performed by cvt.

So it accepting a `wstring` is correct per documentation and it'll be converted to `value_type` internally.

Answer (score 0):

[See this part of the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#value_type).

> value_type is an implementation-defined typedef for the character type used by the operating system to represent pathnames.
>
> Member functions described as returning const string, const wstring, const u16string, or const u32string are permitted to return const string&, const wstring&, const u16string&, or const u32string&, respectively.

This is implementation defined.